# Argument passing to PM2

Tags: javascript, node.js, pm2

I want to put in production a node service :
When I launch my application with my arguments like that : `node ./backend -c "uf4m6fhnh" -s "SPNLGZsUoSpQ=" -o "8696"`. Everything works well.

Now I want to put it in production with PM2 : 
I have tried the 2 ways to to that (CLI and JSON file) like that :

CLI version :

> `pm2 start backend.js --node-args="-c uf4lvm6fhnh -s SPNLGZsUoSpQ= -o 8696" --name MyAppName`

and also :

> `pm2 start backend.js --name MyAppName -- "-c uf4lvm6fhnh -s SPNLGZsUoSpQ= -o 8696"`

Config file (JSON) :

```
{
  "apps": [
    {
      "name": "MyAppName ",
      "script": "./backend.js",
      "node_args": [
          "-c",
          "uf4lvm6fhnh",
          "-s",
          "SPNLGZsUoSpQ=",
          "-o",
          "8696"
        ]
    }
  ]
}
```

and then : `pm2 start myConfigJson.json`

For each of this possible solution, I have the same error in my `pm2 logs` :
`Error: Cannot find module '/home/me/Projects/Project/uf4lvm6fhnh'`
(Note that the not found module is my passed argument)

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `args` instead.

`node_args` is an alias to `interpreter_args` which passes arguments to node itself, rather than the script. As a result, your command line ends up calling `-c|--check` on node itself instead.

See http://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/pm2-doc-single-page/#programmatic-api and https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_c_check